# How can I package a DLL without managed code into my WPF app?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, dll, ilmerge

I've been using [LibZ Container](https://libz.codeplex.com/) for awhile now to bundle DLL files together with my executables, resulting in only needing to copy a single executable file instead of installing a bunch of DLLs. (For those not familiar LibZ Container is an alternative to IL Merge, only that it works with WPF.)

Normally this works great, but today I learned that it doesn't work so great with the SQLite library. In particular, there's one file that fails to package. This is the error message that I get:

> Loading '.\SQLite.Interop.dll'
>
> Failed to load assembly from '.\SQLite.Interop.dll'
>
> Assembly '.\SQLite.Interop.dll' could not be loaded

Looking on the [SQLite FAQ page](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki) I see they state this:

> **Do I need to add an assembly reference to the "sqlite3.dll" or "SQLite.Interop.dll" in my project?**
>
> No, because they are not managed assemblies and contain no managed code.

I must confess I'm not really sure what that means... until now this stuff has mostly been a black box to me that just sort of works. Is there any way to bundle the SQLite.Interop.dll file with the assembly like I'm hoping? Can anyone offer an explanation of why LibZ Container is choking on this DLL file in particular?

Comment: I'm not sure if its choking on it, it seems you are not directly referencing it, so it doesn't package it. The sqlite3.dll is an unmanaged DLL, it is loaded via p/invoke calls from the SQLite.Interop.dll (which should be managed, not unmanaged as the quote says). The SQLite.Interop.dll should be used from whatever SQLite driver you are using. I'm guessing using unmanaged p/invoke dll's is not supported by LibZ, but I'd ask the developers that.

Comment: sqlite3.dll is not necessary for this; that just happened to be addressed in the same FAQ question. As for SQLite.Interop.dll, for some reason it's not generated in the bin/Release folder automatically, although Google searches lead me to believe that at one time (with an older version of SQLite) it used to be copied automatically. I had to find it myself inside the packages/ folder. Without it there, I get exceptions saying it failed to load. So while I don't doubt at all what you're saying about it not being directly referenced, it seems it is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, as Ron already suggested in the comments, this is not possible. Because the two SQLite.Interop.dll files are unmanaged, they can't be bundled inside the executable. They have to stay outside, in their respective x86 and x64 folders, within the same parent directory as the executable. No way around this.